# Merge content of two csv file side by side in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, scripting

My first csv file has content

```
Id Name Result  
1  Ron  Yes  
2  Yon  No
```

while my send csv has the similar content.

```
Id Name Result  
1  Ron  No  
2  Yon  No
```

I want the final output file to have :

```
Id Name Result1 Result2  
1 Ron   Yes    No
```

Can someone please help me with this. I need to make a bash script to make this work.
Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't `Yon` in the result? Anyway, use the `join` command to do this.

Comment: By which rule "Yon" record disappear ?

Comment: Why do you need to write a script when there's a standard command to do it? Is it a homework exercise where you're not allowed to use that program?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome Richi. Your question is off-topic here and on topic on Super User.

Comment: There's an odd lack of commas if that's supposed to be  CSV data...

Comment: Hey @Barmar, I wanted to keep the example minimalistic, so I didnt explain everything. I tried googling and searching on stack overflow a lot, but most of them were merge on rows.

Comment: @Shawn CSV is often used as a general term for files with fields separated by any common delimiter, including space-separated, tab-separated.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), using these input files

```
Id,Name,Result
1,Ron,Yes
2,Yon,No

Id,Name,Result
1,Ron,No
2,Yon,No
```

and running

```
mlr --csv join -j Id,Name --lp 1_ --rp 2_ -f input1.csv input2.csv
```

you will have

```
+----+------+----------+----------+
| Id | Name | 1_Result | 2_Result |
+----+------+----------+----------+
| 1  | Ron  | Yes      | No       |
| 2  | Yon  | No       | No       |
+----+------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` which comes with GNU Coreutils

If you run `join -j 2 a.txt b.txt -o1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3`, you get :

```
Id Name Result Result
1 Ron Yes No
2 Yon No No
```

`-j 2` tells join to join on column two of both files.

`-o ...` tells join which columns to output.

Comment: Or you can use `-o` with join to select which columns to print.

Comment: SO is full of people who like to drive by downvote answers to questions that they think aren't worthy of an answer. You get used to it after a while.

Comment: Shawn, thank you for the explanation.
I hope @Richi, will upvote. I don't want my reputation go down for that.

Comment: Hey @Setop, Thanks so much for your answer. Could you please tell me how to rename the last column to result2?

Comment: @RichiDubey you can pipe the results of the answer here to `awk -v n=1 'FNR == 1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "Result") $i = "Result" n++; }1'` to sequentially number the heading with e.g. `"... Reslult1  Result2"`